# Web-Audio Api and Javascript: Get the correct picks from microphone

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, mediarecorder, wavesurfer.js

I'm doing some experiments and doing some visualizations based on the data received in real time by the microphone.

In this case I want to create a visualization like this:
https://online-voice-recorder.com/es/

or maybe the Mac OS audio recorder 
[image: voice recorder]

I have a full codepen example below please check out but my question is I'm using this:

```
obj.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(obj.frequencyArray)
```

Is that correct for this particular case to obtain the peaks and generate a wave graph? like [wavesurfer library](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) or maybe I need to know more about audio or use some mathematics, I don't know I'm stuck.

here is my full codepen example: 
https://codepen.io/davidtorroija/pen/bZXeqb

**EDITED:** 
Adding more info:
Based on the answer by Brad changing in my example getByteTimeDomainData()

I looked at that method of getByteTimeDomain and is used to create an oscilloscope visualization. I changed to this method in this example and it does not look like. Looking in the array of bytes the minimun is 100 that is to high when there is no sound [new Codepen Example here](https://codepen.io/davidtorroija/pen/gyYrbm)
But maybe is my implementation.
[image: wavegraph of the recording]
By the way I'm taking the max number of the ByteFrequencyArray because I don't know what is the correct strategy to take the peak from there, maybe there is other way to do that? code example below:

```
obj.analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(obj.frequencyArray)


for (var i = 0; i< obj.frequencyArray.length;  i++) {
        if(obj.frequencyArray[i] > max) {
          max = obj.frequencyArray[i];
        } 
      }

var freq = Math.floor(max);

obj.bars.push({
    x: obj.width,
    y: (obj.height / 2) - (freq / 2),
    height: max,
    width: 5
})
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at in your screenshot is actually in the time domain.

For that, you'll want to use [`getByteTimeDomainData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteTimeDomainData) or [`getFloatTimeDomainData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getFloatTimeDomainData).

Comment: Thanks for answer!, but could you explain more, I want to learn and understand the difference, because I looked at that method of getByteTimeDomain and is used to create an oscilloscope visualization.  I changed to this method in this example and it does not look like. Looking in the array of bytes the minimun is 100 that is to high when there is no sound https://codepen.io/davidtorroija/pen/gyYrbm

Comment: @deividsito With no sound, bytes returned from `getByteTimeDomain` should actually hover around `127`.  The actual pressure waves swing negative and positive, so if you're trying to quantize that into bytes that can only represent integers between `0` and `255`, you set your effective zero-pressure value to `127`.  Negative pressure can swing down to `0`, and positive pressure can swing up to `255`.  Either do the math to scale the byte value to the range you want, or use `getFloatTimeDomainData()` which will optimally give you `-1.0` to `1.0` .

Comment: Ok @Brad thanks for the explanation :), let me try that thanks!

Comment: Ok @Brad I have another question when I receive all the time the array of values in lapse of time I received depending of the fftsize 512 or 1024 etc, I'm iterating this array and taking the max value of this array to draw this value in that time lapse. Is that correct or I need to do the average of the array values? Thanks!

Comment: @deividsito Average would approach zero, by definition.  Max and min should be similar to each other in magnitude (but with min being negative).  For just a basic visualization, max is fine.

Comment: Perfect @Brad thanks I just did it :P https://codepen.io/davidtorroija/pen/ZZzLpb